# Launch Selenium IE Driver with pac in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate my app on IE specifically and I want to route my traffic through a specific node. I have been googling around and found a solution that fit my case:

```
DC = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER.copy()

DC["proxy"]={
    'proxyType': proxy.ProxyType.PAC,
    'proxyAutoconfigUrl': self.pac_url,
    "class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
    "autodetect":False
}
self.driver= webdriver.Ie(executable_path=pathToIEdriver,capabilities=DC)
```

Comment: So what's a problem?

Comment: this code doesn't launch the Browser with DesiredCapabilities object but it i write this it launches the browser
`webdriver.Ie(executable_path=pathToIEdriver)`